# Migration in Rails gives back could not find table error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, migration

I made a new migration in order to add a *price* column in my *Ingredients* Active Record. Despite that when I run *rails db:migrate* I get an error saying that the table ingredients does not exist. Here are my console commands:

```
 C:\Users\andri\Desktop\hoagieShop\hoagieShop>rails generate migration 
 AddPriceToIngredients price:decimal, false:null --force
  invoke  active_record
  remove    db/migrate/20190124075954_add_price_to_ingredients.rb
  create    db/migrate/20190124080657_add_price_to_ingredients.rb

C:\Users\andri\Desktop\hoagieShop\hoagieShop>rails db:migrate
== 20190123201200 RemovePriceFromIngrendients: migrating 
======================
-- remove_column(:ingrendients, :price, :decimal)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations 
canceled:
Could not find table ingrendients 
C:/Users/andri/Desktop/hoagieShop/hoagieShop/db/migrate/201901232 
01200_remove_price_from_ingrendients.rb:3:in change
bin/rails:4:in require
bin/rails:4:in <main>

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table ingrendients


C:/Users/andri/Desktop/hoagieShop/hoagieShop/db/migrate/20190123201200_
remove_pr 
ice_from_ingrendients.rb:3:in change
bin/rails:4:in require
bin/rails:4:in <main>
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have removed and added this migration again a few times so I am not sure if this plays any role.
Does anyone have an idea as to why this happens? I appreciate any help!

Comment: There is migration `20190123201200` which should remove a specific column (`price`) from a table (`ingrendients`). But the whole table doesn't exist – `Could not find table ingrendients`. What exactly is unclear to you?

Comment: @spickermann but I type AddPriceToIngredients not AddPriceToIngrendients.

Comment: @spickermann the next thing I do is rails db:migrate and the rest of the commands you see are generated automatically.

Comment: @spickermann the next thing I do is rails db:migrate and the rest of the commands you see are generated automatically.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a simple typo in your `20190123201200_remove_price_from_ingrendients.rb` migration, and not in the migrations you've generated, see:

`-- remove_column(:ingrendients, :price, :decimal)`

It should probably be `ingredients` not `ingrendients` (extra `n` before `dients`)

Comment: This is not something I typed myself. I enter first *rails generate migration 
 AddPriceToIngredients price:decimal, false:null --force* and then *rails db:migrate* and the rest of the commands are generated automatically as part of the error

Comment: @ffblord The error isn't coming from the `AddPriceToIngredients` migration you've just created, rather from a migration created yesterday which is contained in the `20190123201200_remove_price_from_ingrendients.rb`. When you run `rails db:migrate`, it runs all migrations in the order they were created in the order they were created (or rather, the timestamps on the filename), starting from the one after the last one it successfully ran. So seems like you have a migration from yesterday its trying to run that wasn't run before, which is what's throwing the error.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It looks like maybe some migrations were created and then not run, and possibly a migration file may have been manually deleted too. That would cause the behavior the OP is seeing.